# mongoose index already exists with different options

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I am implementing search result view to my app.
I figured out that mongoose internally provide full text search function with $text.

I put the code below to Post.js

```
PostSchema.index({desc: 'text'}); //for example
```

Here's the code I put in my routing file route/posts.js

```
Post.find({$text: {$search : 'please work!'}}).exec(function (err, posts) {...})
```

The error message I come up with is below

```
Index with pattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 } already exists with different options
```

Would there any body who know how to deal with this error and figure out?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check on which field you have your text index defined. Right now mongodb allows only one text index per collection. so if you have defined a text index on desc column and try to use that index on some other column you are bound to get this error.

can you try to query your index and see on which column you created it. To get indexes you can do

```
db.collection.getIndexes()
```

and it will return something like this

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "some.ns"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "desc_text",
        "ns" : "some.ns",
        "weights" : {
            "title" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]
```

now if you want to scope in other columns also to use this index simply drop this index

```
db.collection.dropIndex('desc_text');
```

and then recreate it by including all columns you want to be covered by text index,

```
db.collection.createIndex({
    title:'text;,
    body: 'text;,
    desc: 'text',
    ...... and so on
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear and quick solution. It works now!

Comment: in my case I changed a column name so I had to drop and recreate

Comment: ofcourse, if one the column on which index is defined then the index needs to be recreated.